# What is/was the smallest orbital launch system, by total mass?

Tags: launch-vehicle

What is (or was, if it's no longer in use) the system with lowest launch mass, capable of putting (any) payload in (or reaching) LEO? "How small" did we get with orbital flights?

(and yes, I realize economically that's a rather poor idea; still I'd like to know what was attempted.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Juno 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_I) had a payload of 11 kg to LEO from a start mass of 29 t.

[Diamant-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamant) had a start weight of 18.4 t, payload 100 kg to LEO.

[Black Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Arrow) had a start weight of 18.1 t, payload 100 kg to LEO.

[Vanguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_%28rocket%29), start weight of 10 t, payload 9 kg to LEO.

[Lambda 4S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_4S) had a start weight of 9.4 t, payload 26 kg to LEO.

[Caleb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTS-EV-2_Caleb) was an air-launched missile theoretically capable of attaining orbit. Start weight of 1350 kg, payload 7 kg to LEO.

[Project Pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTS-EV-1_Pilot) was an air-launched missile theoretically capable of attaining orbit. Start weight of 900 kg, payload 1 kg to LEO.

Comment: Lambda 4S yes could be smallest, but Diamant-A & Black Arrow are just know or famous. Some other rockets in terms of launch weight are smaller than these two : Vanguard (10.05 t) and Scout (17.85 t) USA, Capricornio (15 t) Spain, Haas (16 t) Romania, SLV (17 t) India. In terms of payload it is possible another rocket in development of Australia, AUSROC Nano designed for a 10 kg payload, but of course this isn't opperational and who knows it will ever fly and if its max payload will be 10 kg or more.

Comment: I arrived at my answer through several iterations, starting with Juno and Diamant. I left them in to give an idea of the playing field.

Comment: Thanks :) I wonder about thoughts of the pilot of the plane from which Calebs  were launched, They had an uncanny tendency to explode on ignition, which would in this case probably mean "adjacent to the airplane".

Comment: Vanguard 1. 10t launch mass, 1.5kg payload.

Comment: Wikipedia has payload at 9 kg...

Comment: It doesn't seem fair to neglect the mass of the plane for the air-launched rockets. That's like neglecting the mass of stage 1 for a multi-stage rocket.

Comment: @user2357112 It's not part of the rocket equation though.

Comment: Regardless, Lambda 4S is the lightest system that actually achieved orbital insertion of payload. None of the missile systems reached orbit.

Comment: @SF.: [Not anymore!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)#SS-520-5)

Comment: Are they sorted by cost? Which was cheapest of the alternatives listed?

Comment: They are in the order in which I found them. Theyr'e also mostly really old projects (from the 1950s-1960s). No idea about the cost.

Answer (score 10):

The smallest launch system (by total mass) that has *actually put something in orbit* is the [SS-520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)#SS-520) (first successful orbital launch 3 February 2018).

- Start mass: 2,600 kg
- Payload to LEO: 9 kg

---

Current design and future designs:
[image: Series size comparisons]

Comment: [Will JAXA try again to launch TRICOM-1 with the “world's smallest orbital rocket” SS-520-4 again?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22471/12102)

Comment: @uhoh: [Yes, JAXA did.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)#SS-520-5)

Comment: I've just made an update to the answer there, and linked back to your answer here. Great catch!

Comment: I added a picture- hopefully it helps not hurts! The first thing I did when I saw this answer is look for some visuals! Looks like they plan to get even smaller too!!!

Comment: Seems they have plans for a four stage nano- if that isn't cool I don't know what is.