# If there "won't be" rockets to launch individual cubesats, then why did JAXA build exactly that? (SS-520-xx)

Tags: cubesat, launch-vehicle, jaxa, sounding-rocket

The question [Why isn't there a rocket to launch a single cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36261/12102) has several good answers that explain why there isn't and/or will not likely be one, based mostly on commercial viability, consistent with the gist of the question's text.

Yet [one answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37903/12102) cites JAXA's launch of the single 3U cubeast TRICOM-1 into orbit using [the “world's smallest orbital rocket”](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22471/12102) the SS-520-5.

If there are so many good answers explaining why there won't be rockets to launch individual cubesats, one might ask:

1. Then why *is there one* and why did JAXA develop it?
2. What are the long term plans for this launch solution (that shouldn't exist)?

---

[image] [image]

[Source](http://spaceflight101.com/ss-520-4-rocket-launches-on-experimental-mission/) Click image(s) for full size.

Comment: The answer to that question was "there's no business case" The answer to this question is "Governments don't need a business case"

Comment: @JCRM I agree with your premise, but that's only a partial answer to #1 here. Any idea what JAXA might be up to in this case?

Comment: Governments think about things other than profit, especially strategic considerations. They might be paying to maintain the capability to do anti-satellite strikes.

Comment: Or could just be government largesse, jobs program, Japanese pork (like US space shuttle was a pork project)

Comment: @RokoMijic I object to your blanket characterization of the shuttle program as a 'pork project'.

Comment: perhaps, but that would take us off topic here. Point is that governments have other motivations than what's efficient, useful etc.

Answer (score 10):

The SS-520-5 launcher is not intended to be an operational vehicle.

> - ... the  SS-520-5  was  also  an  experiment to  construct  a     minimum  system  that  can  be  established with  a  micro-small rocket  and  whether  future  AFSS will be established.
> - ...was conducted as a demonstration of compact and light substrate    technology, consumer manufacturing technology, quality assurance  technology using COTS technology. We demonstrated technology of   Japanese COTS parts companies that can withstand severe launch environmental conditions.
> - Through this development we were able to confirm that the  COTS     parts  made  in  Japan  function  with  satellites and rockets.This  affordable   technology   can   be   used   for the development  technology of low cost rockets.

(AFSS = **A**utonomous **F**light **S**afety **S**ystem, COTS = **C**ommercial **O**ff **T**he **S**helf)

[Source](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4120&context=smallsat)

Comment: So SS-520-5 was a demonstration of technology. Though it succeeded in putting a satellite into orbit I think that "...is not intended to be an operational vehicle" means it's a technology demonstration and perhaps not a final product. But I'm not sure if this is a complete answer to my question yet, specifically item #2. Are you suggesting that the technologies demonstrated will only be used in much larger rockets and that they *will not* be using this to launch individual cubesats? Has that been ruled out in any way?

Comment: your answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37918/12102) is an excellent match for [How do small, spin stabilized launchers follow a Rhumb line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37920/12102)

Comment: What are they trying to demonstrate?

Comment: @ikrase 2nd bullet